# Bluetooth suddenly disappeared

Tags: bluetooth

I am very frustrated.

Turned the PC on, worked some time with my bluetooth mouse on, suddenly the mouse stopped working, the occasional OFF-ON the mouse did not help (as it usually does), I went to Settings, and acctually did see the Bluetooth settings dissapeared before me!

I read up everything, watched tutorials on Youtube, in Device Manager have found Bluetooth in hidden, but nothing worked to put it back on (in many tutorials the start looked the same, but did not fix it for me).

I tried to uninstal it, reinstal it from the Intel site.

The bluetooth is installed, services are running, still, its nowere to be found.......

This is the second time this happened - the first time it has fixed miraculously itsself after a few hours of me reading up and trying everything...........when I gave up, in some time it just resumed.

Please help, I have spent all night on it...... (tried everything written and in all youtube tutorials), it did not happen after update, I tried updating the driver first, followed all the tutorials. The restore did not work, and now the restore point is gone........

Do not want to refresh the PC....

Answer (score 0):

Since turning the mouse off and back on sometimes fixed this issue in the past, it sounds like a problem with the mouse, not your computer. Actually, it sounds like it could just need a new battery; I'd replace it just to make sure. When it's on, is there a green/blue light on the mouse? Does it turn red or start blinking?

If it's not the battery, you could also try buying or borrowing a new Bluetooth mouse (or other Bluetooth device, eg. keyboard, speaker, headphones) for a while and see if you run into the same problem. If you do, then it's obviously a problem with your computer; if not then the problem is probably the mouse.